# How to check if a class exists in an array of div elements-Extjs3

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have an array of elements coming from the store:

```
var array = [
    <div class="tag-selected"><div class="inner">Test</div></div>,
    <div class="tag-over tag-selected"><div class="inner">Test2</div></div>,
    <div class="tag-selected"><div class="inner">Test3</div></div>
];

Ext.iterate(array, function(tag) {
    // Want to check if ('.tag-over') exists, in this case should return div with Test2
}));
```

If the div contains that particular class, retain and remove all others from the array. In short keep the element who has a class `('.tag-over')`.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use like this:

```
var newArray = Ext.Array.filter(array, function(tag) {
    return Ext.get(tag).hasCls('.tag-over');
});
```

Comment: For extjs3 you use my previous answer before being edited. That is standard javascript.

Comment: so edited the code above with your suggestion, still not sure how can i delete the elements not containing the '.tag-over' class.

Comment: IF you use array.filter, then it will remove the elements from the new array.

Comment: You are still using Ext.iterate. It doesnt remove anything.

Comment: you're right, but what shld i use for extjs3? I dont see any answer expect for the one listed above

Comment: Click on `edited` where you see Mr. Polywhirl under my post. There you ll see my original answer before he edited. That will work in all extjs versions, because its a part of standard javascript. Only not working under ie9.